# SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when setting ciphers on tomcat 7 server

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, encryption, resttemplate, sslhandshakeexception

I have a Tomcat7 web-server which I tried to configure to accept secure connections by adding this connector to the `server.xml` file:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true"
           acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           keyAlias="server"
           keystoreFile="c:\opt\engine\conf\tc.keystore"
           keystorePass="o39UI12z"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="15"
           port="8443"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           redirectPort="8443"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I'm using a self-signed certificate generated using this command:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool -genkeypair -keystore c:\opt\engine\conf\tc.keystore -storepass o39UI12z-keypass o39UI12z-dname "cn=Company, ou=Company, o=Com, c=US" -alias server -validity 36500
```

On the client side I have a spring application that connects with the server using `RestTemplate`. On application context startup I initalize the `restTemplate` instance this way:

```
final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =
        new MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory(new NullHostNameVerifier(), serverInfo);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

The class MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory  extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
    .getLogger(MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory.class);

private final HostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier;
private final ServerInfo serverInfo;

public MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory (final HostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier,
    final ServerInfo serverInfo) {
    this.hostNameVerifier = hostNameVerifier;
    this.serverInfo = serverInfo;
}

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(final HttpURLConnection connection, final String httpMethod)
    throws IOException {
    if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(hostNameVerifier);
        ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(initSSLContext()
            .getSocketFactory());
    }
    super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
}

private SSLContext initSSLContext() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");

        // Set ssl trust manager. Verify against our server thumbprint
        final SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
        final SslThumbprintVerifier verifier = new SslThumbprintVerifier(serverInfo);
        final ThumbprintTrustManager thumbPrintTrustManager =
            new ThumbprintTrustManager(null, verifier);
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { thumbPrintTrustManager }, null);
        return ctx;
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error(
            "An exception was thrown while trying to initialize HTTP security manager.", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Up until here everything worked fine.** When I put a break point in the SslThumbprintVerifier class, the code reached to this point and also to the NullHostNameVerifier class. This was tested in production and worked great.

Now I wanted to extend security by limiting the cipher suites and I added this property to the Connector I presented at the beginning:

```
ciphers="TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

Now when I'm running the client code I get this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

This happens in the `restTemplate.doExecute()` method. The code doesn't reach to the thumbprint verifier class nor to the host name verifier class as it did before adding the ciphers.

In debug I checked the `ctx.getSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites()` which showed:

```
[SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5]
```

and also checked `ctx.getSocketFactory().getDefaultCipherSuites()`:

```
[SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

and lastly the `ctx.getSupportedSSLParameters().getCipherSuites()`:

```
[SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5]
```

As far as I understand, if there's an intersection between the client's supported/enabled cipher suites and the server's supported cipher suites it should work (we have such intersection with `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` for example). And yet I'm getting this error.

In the next step I added this java parameter:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake,failure
```

The log showed only the client-hello, with no server-hello response:

```
[2013-03-20 15:29:51.315] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        trigger seeding of SecureRandom 
[2013-03-20 15:29:51.315] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        done seeding SecureRandom 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.894] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Allow unsafe renegotiation: false 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.894] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Allow legacy hello messages: true 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.894] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Is initial handshake: true 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.894] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Is secure renegotiation: false 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.894] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        %% No cached client session 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.894] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        *** ClientHello, TLSv1 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.941] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        RandomCookie:  GMT: 1363720446 bytes = { 99, 249, 173, 214, 110, 82, 58, 52, 189, 92, 74, 169, 133, 128, 250, 109, 160, 64, 112, 253, 50, 160, 255, 196, 85, 93, 33, 172 } 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.941] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Session ID:  {} 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.941] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.956] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        Compression Methods:  { 0 } 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.956] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        *** 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.956] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        data-service-pool-37, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.956] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        data-service-pool-37, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.956] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        data-service-pool-37, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.972] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        data-service-pool-37, called closeSocket() 
[2013-03-20 15:30:38.972] [INFO ] data-service-pool-37          System.out                                                        data-service-pool-37, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

When removing the ciphers from the server.xml it works again.
**Also I will mention that I'm testing both the server and the client on the same machine.** I tried setting the server's ip in the client request to 'localhost' and to the actual machine ip and it didn't work in both cases. Also, I had this server running on a different linux machine (the keystore was generated on the linux machine with a linux path of course) and still - it works without the ciphers and stops working with the ciphers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I got this issue solved. It appears that by creating a self-signed certificate, using keytool, **without providing -keyalg parameter** makes the key-pair algorithm default to DSA. None of my ciphers suite included DSA algorithm. In that case, although the client and the server had intersection between their cipher-suites, neither was suitable for the key algoritm.

Adding `-keyalg RSA` when generating the keystore, solved the problem.