# Access Https Rest Service using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, rest, https, certificate, resttemplate

Can anybody provide me with a code sample to access the rest service URL secured with HTTPS using the Spring Rest template?

I have the certificate, username and password. Basic Authentication is used on the server-side and I want to create a client that can connect to that server using a provided certificate, username and password (if needed).

Answer (score 30):

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File(keyStoreFile)),
  keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
  new SSLContextBuilder()
    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray())
    .build(),
    NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(
  socketFactory).build();

ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
  httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
MyRecord record = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, MyRecord.class);
LOG.debug(record.toString());
```

Comment: Do you how to achieve this in spring 5 ?

Comment: This is completely insecure. No server certificate verification (`TrustSelfSignedStrategy`), no hostname verification (`NoopHostnameVerifier`). The key material provided is for client-certificate authentication, but the question says it's using HTTP Basic authentication. In this context, what's loaded from the keystore isn't going to be used at all.

Answer (score 18):

Here is some code that will give you the general idea.

You need to create a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` in order to trust the certificate.
It looks like this:

```
final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =
        new MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER, serverInfo);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
```

This is the implementation for `MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory`:

```
public class MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory  extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

private final HostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier;
private final ServerInfo serverInfo;

public MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory (final HostnameVerifier hostNameVerifier,
    final ServerInfo serverInfo) {
    this.hostNameVerifier = hostNameVerifier;
    this.serverInfo = serverInfo;
}

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(final HttpURLConnection connection, final String httpMethod)
    throws IOException {
    if (connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(hostNameVerifier);
        ((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(initSSLContext()
            .getSocketFactory());
    }
    super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
}

private SSLContext initSSLContext() {
    try {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");

        // Set ssl trust manager. Verify against our server thumbprint
        final SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
        final SslThumbprintVerifier verifier = new SslThumbprintVerifier(serverInfo);
        final ThumbprintTrustManager thumbPrintTrustManager =
            new ThumbprintTrustManager(null, verifier);
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { thumbPrintTrustManager }, null);
        return ctx;
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error(
            "An exception was thrown while trying to initialize HTTP security manager.", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this case my `serverInfo` object contains the thumbprint of the server.
You need to implement the `TrustManager` interface to get
the `SslThumbprintVerifier` or any other method you want to verify your certificate (you can also decide to also always return `true`).

The value `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER` allows all host names.
If you need to verify the host name,
you will need to implement it differently.

I'm not sure about the user and password and how you implemented it.
Often,
you need to add a header to the `restTemplate` named `Authorization`
with a value that looks like this: `Base: <encoded user+password>`.
The `user+password` must be `Base64` encoded.

Comment: A lot of my code was taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544116/sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-when-setting-ciph

Comment: Looks quite clean except for the "System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");" line. Is there a way without setting some system-level things? I'm having a similar problem and want to isolate the certificate-related problem to just one bean.

Comment: @Ruslan - Wow, you took me back with this answer. Unfortunately, it was too long ago and I have already switched two workplaces since then so I don't have the source code and I couldn't remember why I did things the way I did. I'm pretty sure there was a way around it, I'll try to see if I can find another way and if so I'll post it here.

Comment: I found the solution already. Let me post another answer with it, because it's not trivial. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You should better add `SslThumbprintVerifier`class.

Answer (score 12):

This is a solution with **no deprecated** class or method :
(**Java 8** approved)

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

**Important information : Using NoopHostnameVerifier is a security risk**

Comment: Any time you ignore certificates it's a security risk. I'm assuming (hoping?) OP is planning on using this for testing

Answer (score 4):

One point from me. I used a mutual cert authentication with spring-boot microservices. The following is working for me, key points here are
`keyManagerFactory.init(...)` and  `sslcontext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom())` lines of code without them, at least for me, things did not work. Certificates are packaged by PKCS12.

```
@Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
private String keyStorePassword;
@Value("${server.ssl.key-store-type}")
private String keyStoreType;
@Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
private Resource resource;

private RestTemplate getRestTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() throws Exception {
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
}

private HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);

    if (resource.exists()) {
        InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();

        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                trustStore.load(inputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
                keyManagerFactory.init(trustStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find resource: " + resource.getFilename());
    }

    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
    sslcontext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
            new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}, null, getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

    return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
}
```

Comment: It might be clearer if you renamed `trustStore` into `keyStore`, since you're using it for the key manager, not the trust manager.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up with for the similar problem. The idea is the same as in @Avi's answer, but I also wanted to avoid the static "System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");", so that any adjustments won't affect the system. Inspired by an answer from here http://www.coderanch.com/t/637177/Security/Disabling-handshake-message-Java

```
public class MyCustomClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) {
    try {
        if (!(connection instanceof HttpsURLConnection)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An instance of HttpsURLConnection is expected");
        }

        HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) connection;

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }

                }
        };
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        httpsConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new MyCustomSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()));

        httpsConnection.setHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);

        super.prepareConnection(httpsConnection, httpMethod);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}

/**
 * We need to invoke sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"SSLv3"});
 * see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html (Java 8 section)
 */
private static class MyCustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public MyCustomSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final Socket socket, final String host, final int port, final boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        final Socket underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port) throws IOException {
        final Socket underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port);
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final String host, final int port, final InetAddress localAddress, final int localPort) throws IOException {
        final Socket underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final InetAddress host, final int port) throws IOException {
        final Socket underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port);
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final InetAddress host, final int port, final InetAddress localAddress, final int localPort) throws IOException {
        final Socket underlyingSocket = delegate.createSocket(host, port, localAddress, localPort);
        return overrideProtocol(underlyingSocket);
    }

    private Socket overrideProtocol(final Socket socket) {
        if (!(socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("An instance of SSLSocket is expected");
        }
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"SSLv3"});
        return socket;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Insecure because there's no certificate verification and no host name verification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a raw HttpClient with SSL support, something like this:

```
@Test
public void givenAcceptingAllCertificatesUsing4_4_whenUsingRestTemplate_thenCorrect() 
throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient
      = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
        .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory 
      = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

    ResponseEntity<String> response 
      = new RestTemplate(requestFactory).exchange(
      urlOverHttps, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode().value(), equalTo(200));
}
```

[from: Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl#resttemplate_ssl-1)