# Access Https Rest Service using Spring 5 RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have looked at [Access Https Rest Service using Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619871/access-https-rest-service-using-spring-resttemplate). But that is for spring 4 and things have changed in spring 5. I was hoping somebody had code sample on how to use Resttemplate to make https call. I have the certs and the auth. I have added the cert to jre/lib/security but spring doesn't seem to read from there.

Comment: Thanks for the -1. when you get it working come back

Answer (score 0):

As I discover, when rest client send a request with `X-Forwarded-Ssl` key with `on` in its header, links become `https`.